# visual studio keeps adding a _1 to a project name crashing the build

Tags: visual-studio

I created a project, lets say named AddonLib, which is part of a big solution. For some unknown reason, the folder where the source code was put was named AddonLib_1. I've been trying to get rid of that "_1" for too long now and is driving me crazy. Things I've tried:

- removed the project, from TFS and the solution. Renamed the directory. When I try to add the project again, I get the message "The project file "blabla\AddonLib_1\AddonLib.vcxproj" has been moved, renamed or is not on your computer".
- Edited the xml file of the solution. Check the project file just to be sure. Removed any trace of the project with and without _1. The project AddonLib is no longer part of the solution. Try to add it back again, same error as before.
- Cleared the VS cache following the instructions [here](https://www.matteopozzani.com/visual-studio-cache-cleanup/). Repeated previous step. Same error.

I cannot find any reference to AddonLib_1 on my code, xml files, anything. But everytime I try to load the project, I get the same error.

Looking for the string "AddonLib_1" using **findstr** gives no results...

This causes the build to break. Even if there are no references (that I can find) to AddonLib_1, when building in the server I get an error "project AddonLib_1/AddonLib.vcxproj could not be found blablabla"....

Besides the solution xml file, the project xml file, the xml files of the few projects that depend on this project, where else can the information that once the project was in the directory AddonLib_1 ?

**More info**:
I can remove the project. Remove it from TFS, from the solution, and delete the directory. Create a new project with the desired name. Add the source and header files. Now, I need to add some info to the project xml file. If I open the xml file and edit, when I try to load back the project (Which was loaded before!) I get the same error message. If I open the xml again, undo the minor change I did, I still get the error. Again, this is in a new project, starting from zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by removing the .suo file as described in this apparently unrelated  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002088/the-project-file-has-been-moved-renamed-or-is-not-on-your-computer)

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to clean up the references to my old project from the applicationhost.config file in the same .vs hidden folder